# Trying to add overlays to map error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, overlays, here-api

I just cleared layers off my mapping program and when I try to add a new layer I receive this error message.

```
newSystem.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
Source=System.Windows
InnerException:
```

If anyone knows why this is I would very much appreciate your assistance

```
  private void loadZoomLevel12Pics()
    {
        map1.Layers.Clear();
        MapLayer pinLayer = new MapLayer();
        // Create a new empty Pushpin
        // Beny Sur- Mer War Cemetary 
        MapOverlay pinOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        // Add the location of the Pushpin using latitude and longitude.
        pinOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.33783000, -0.45215600);
        //Image pinOverlayImage = new Image();
        pinOverlayImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/Hedgehog.png", UriKind.Relative));
        pinOverlay.Content = pinOverlayImage;
        pinOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
        pinOverlayImage.Opacity = 0.8;
        pinOverlayImage.Height = 8;
        pinOverlayImage.Width = 8;
        pinOverlayImage.Tap += pinOverlayImage_Tap;
        pinLayer.Add(pinOverlay);
        map1.Layers.Add(pinLayer);
```

Then these pictures are cleared and a new zoom level is loaded

```
  private void loadZoomLevel13Pics()
    {
        map1.Layers.Clear();
        MapLayer pinLayer = new MapLayer();
        // Create a new empty Pushpin
        // Beny Sur- Mer War Cemetary 
        MapOverlay pinOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        // Add the location of the Pushpin using latitude and longitude.
        pinOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.33783000, -0.45215600);
        //Image pinOverlayImage = new Image();
        pinOverlayImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/Hedgehog.png", UriKind.Relative));
        pinOverlay.Content = pinOverlayImage;
        pinOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
        pinOverlayImage.Opacity = 0.8;
        pinOverlayImage.Height = 30;
        pinOverlayImage.Width = 30;
        pinOverlayImage.Tap += pinOverlayImage_Tap;
        pinLayer.Add(pinOverlay);
        map1.Layers.Add(pinLayer); // THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE PROBLEM
```

All of the images are declared globally because they are used in other functions/methods inside the program.

It seems like its trying to add the same layer that was previously added and is having difficulty doing so, but all of the layers are cleared on the first line of the method.

Comment: Include the code in your question

Comment: okay I did @AlaaMasoud

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this as I am seeing the same issue in my app?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue using a global polygon instead of an image. The issue is that even though you are calling map1.Layers.Clear() this does not get done immediately after it is called therefore you need to create a new image. In general, this can be fixed by not using global/instance variables for the overlay.Content...just declare it each time and assign it to the Content.